# React suddenly throwing ''Box' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Box'?' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

In my react app today I suddenly have 193 errors, according to VS Code, first of which is:

```
'Box' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Box'?
```

Code:

```
return (
  <Box px={Padding.medium} flexDirection="column" justifyContent= "center">
```

this worked fine yesterday, no changes have been made and npm start runs the code OK.

What might be causing this?

EDIT: my tsconfig.json:

```
        {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest", "dom-mediacapture-record"],
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
      },
      "include": ["src", "tests/*.test.ts"]

}
```

EDIT2: I have made changes to the code done `npm start` and it runs with changes showing. But still the errors are flagged.

EDIT3: the problem disappeared but moved to another file. This one  imports PageX but when it is referred to later:

```
  render() {

  return <PageX
```

`'PageX' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof PageX'?`

Comment: Is your `tsconfig` including all the necessary files, and has correct jsx definitions?

Comment: I imagine since it worked yesterday. But I am new to this so will post it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using vscode. It turns out I had a typo in my filename. I had `MyFile,js` instead of `MyFile.js`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35700005)